# How to implement a quantum_and() gate

Tags: quantum-gate, programming

I have `encoder()` and `decoder()` functions as follows:

```python
def encoder(x: int=0, y: int=0, n=4):
    """
    An encoder to convert two n-bit nonnegative integers (uint) x and y to a 2n-qubit QuantumCircuit.
    This encoder will be used by autograder.
    """
    assert x >= 0 and x < 2**n and isinstance(n,int), f"Your input x must be an integer in the range [0,{(2**n)-1}]."
    assert y >= 0 and y < 2**n and isinstance(n,int), f"Your input y must be an integer in the range [0,{(2**n)-1}]."

    qc = QuantumCircuit(n*2)
    
    for i in range(n):
        if x >= 2**(n-i-1):
            qc.x(n-i-1)
            x -= 2**(n-i-1)

    for i in range(n):
        if y >= 2**(n-i-1):
            qc.x(2*n-i-1)
            y -= 2**(n-i-1)
    
    return qc

def decoder(qc: QuantumCircuit, n=4):
    """
    A decoder to convert a QuantumCircuit to an n-bit nonnegative integer from the simulation histogram
    by measuring the first n qubits in the quantum circuit.
    The result should be deterministic on a noise-free machine, hence shot=1 is used for simulation.
    This decoder will be used by autograder.
    """
    assert n >= 1
    assert isinstance(qc, QuantumCircuit)
    assert qc.num_qubits >= n

    n_qubits = qc.num_qubits
    n_clbits = max(n, qc.num_clbits)

    qr = QuantumRegister(n_qubits)
    cr = ClassicalRegister(n_clbits)
    qc_base = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
    qc = qc_base.compose(qc)

    simulator = QasmSimulator()
    qc.measure(list(range(n)), list(range(n)))
    cc = transpile(qc, simulator)
    job = simulator.run(cc, shots=1)
    result = list(job.result().get_counts(cc).keys())[0]

    z = 0
    for i in range(n):
        z += int(result[i])*2**(n-i-1)

    return z
```

How to implement the `quantum_and` gate? Any suggestions and clues would be helpful.

```python
def quantum_and():
    """
    An N-qubit quantum circuit which calculates the AND result of input1 on [q0] and input2 on [q1],
    The output will be measured on [q0].
    You need to decide the amount of additional qubits needed to implement the function.
    The function must be compatible with the provided encoder(n=1) and decoder(n=1).
    N must be either 2 or 3.
    Args: 
        None
    Return:
        qc: Your QuantumCircuit
    """
```

Comment: Have a look at Toffoli gate. It behaves like AND provided target qubit is initialized to state $|0\rangle$. See more here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate